# add label to specific datapoint in linechart

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have a datlin line chart,

```
x = unix timestamps
y = values between 30 and 90
```

For a specific timestamp, I want to add a marker with a comment to the graph,
to explain why there is such a break in the graph.

Can you point me to the right class or method?

Answer (score 0):

**You can only place textboxes at positions relative to the image dimensions in jpgraph.**

See http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/Text.html

---

**Try callback as an alternative...**

The best you can do is place labels at x,y graph coordinates as shown here:

http://artfuladvection.com/resource/img/plotT2.png

Try this:

```
function xyCallback($yval) {
  global $datax, $idx;
  return "Your Text String Here" . $youcanalsoaddvars;
}

$graph = new Graph(...);
$graph->SetScale("intlin");
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay,$datax);
$p1->value->SetFormatCallback('xyCallback');
$p1->value->Show();
```

Comment: I refuse using globals but I like the idea with a callback on the values.. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Let me know if you figure out a better method, so I can stop using global myself.  Not sure what else to do!